# How to choose zookeeper and regionserver

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

What is a good practice for setting regionserver and zookeeper quorum ?

I have a small hadoop cluster with 16 nodes. Following the example given in http://hbase.apache.org/book/example_config.html I choose as regionserver the 16 nodes and a subset of these nodes as zookeeper.

But when one job is launched by a node which is not in the list corresponding to hbase.zookeeper.quorum I get the following error :

> 13/08/23 15:40:05 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
>   to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to
>   authenticate using SASL (unknown error) 13/08/23 15:40:05 WARN
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error,
>   closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
>   13/08/23 15:40:05 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
>   to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate
>   using SASL (unknown error) 13/08/23 15:40:05 INFO
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session 13/08/23 15:40:05 WARN
>   zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper
>   exception:
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid 13/08/23 15:40:05
>   INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 2000ms before retry #1...

So it tries to conncet for 600 sec and then return

> Task attempt_xxx failed to report status for 60 seconds. Killing!

After a few attempts it changes node and if by chance the new node belongs to the zookeeper list then the job finishes with succes.

Is this normal?

I ended up adding all nodes to the zookeeper list but I would like to know if it is a good practice. Also is there anycase where the list of regionserver should differ from the node list?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't look like what you're doing is a good practice.  For a 16 RS cluster, 1 ZK node should be just fine.

Check out the [ZK Admin guide](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_CrossMachineRequirements):

> For the ZooKeeper service to be active,
>   there must be a majority of non-failing machines that can communicate
>   with each other. To create a deployment that can tolerate the failure
>   of F machines, you should count on deploying 2xF+1 machines. Thus, a
>   deployment that consists of three machines can handle one failure, and
>   a deployment of five machines can handle two failures. Note that a
>   deployment of six machines can only handle two failures since three
>   machines is not a majority. For this reason, ZooKeeper deployments are
>   usually made up of an odd number of machines.

Although it doesn't say it there, a ZK cluster should be no bigger than 7 nodes.  Given the recommendation of an odd number of nodes, that leaves the options of 1, 3, 5, and 7.  Again for a smallish cluster like yours, 1 should suffice, but 3 will give you resiliency.  5 is probably overkill.  7 definitely is.

Also, looking at the error you pasted:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

This would appear to indicate either:

- Hadoop misconfiguration: you pointed to the wrong server/port, or the service is not currently running, or more likely -
- Network misconfiguration, such as a firewall like iptables running

Comment: thank you for your answer , and what about region servers (always the same as the nodes)?

Comment: RegionServers should be colocated with DataNodes.

Comment: 1 is not enough for a production cluster as zookeeper becomes a single point of failure. 3 should be more than enough for the cluster size

Comment: Then how should I proceed to find out why I get java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused ? Thanks

Comment: @lizzie: Did you update Hbase configuration files in all the nodes to point to Zookeeper servers you are using?

Comment: all the nodes have the same config files